# Oracle sql, trigger on tables in different schemes

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert

I use following sql to create my trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERT_LOG
AFTER INSERT 
ON EXTERNAL_SCHEME.PAYMENT
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
INSERT INTO MY_SCHEMA.DM_LOGGER(ID, TECHNOLOGY, WORKFLOW, NAME_EVENT, TIME_EVENT)
VALUES (PAYMENT.id, 'Repository', 'UP', (select repo.name from
pay_repository repo join pay_pmt pay on repo.id = pay_pmt.repository_id
where repo.id = pay.repository_id),(select to_char(SYSDATE, 'hh24:mi:ss') from dual));
END;
```

When I execute this trigger I get following exception:

```
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to change the current username or password
without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if
attempting to install a database without the necessary operating
system privileges.

When Trusted Oracle is configure in DBMS MAC, this error may occur
if the user was granted the necessary privilege at a higher label
than the current login.

*Action:   Ask the database administrator to perform the operation or grant
the required privileges.

For Trusted Oracle users getting this error although granted the
the appropriate privilege at a higher label, ask the database
administrator to regrant the privilege at the appropriate label
```

I don't get it. I have connection to both schemes and I never want to change something. What is wrong?

Comment: It's just that the user trying to execute trigger does not have the privileges to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the privileges seems to be missing,please execute,

```
grant create trigger to schemaname;
```

if it still gives the error then the select privileges might be missing on the tables of other schemas, for that you can run this,

```
grant select on otherschema.table_name to <schema_name> ;
```

Comment: I asked the db admin to grant me the right of creating and using triggers, but I still get the error.

Comment: EXTERNAL_SCHEME
MY_SCHEMA

which among these schmeas are you accesing the table from, ?
the grants needs to be given to the schema where the trigger is being created

Comment: I was doing it on MY_SCHEMA but I got the privileges on the EXTERNAL_SCHEME. Sorry bad mistak from me, thanks this solved it.